# Laravel/vuejs Change boolean value from 0 to 1

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a question I need to create a 2 factor authentication only now the value of a colum in the database will be set to true. He is default to false. I know the database adds this as tinyint so the value should be switched to 1.

[image: When that button is clicked he need to change to 1]

So i have try something but didnt work.. im very new with laravel and vuejs. so its hard for me. I hope one of you can help me out of this struggle

My 2 factor vue. So you can see the v-switch thats the button..

```js
<template>
    <v-container class="user-form-lime" fluid grid-list-xl>
        <v-form>

            <v-layout row wrap>

                <v-flex xs12 md6>

                     <v-switch v-model="tfaEnabled"
                                   label="Tweefactor authenticatie"
                                   name="tfaEnabled"
                                   prepend-icon="lock"
                                   @change="change" />


                </v-flex>

                    <v-flex xs12 md6>


                        <v-text-field v-if="tfaEnabled"
                                      v-model="google2fa.token"
                                      label="Token"
                                      :rules="[rules.required]"
                                      type="text" />

                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>

            <v-layout row wrap>

                <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-btn color="success" @click="submit">
                        Opslaan
                    </v-btn>
                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>

        </v-form>

    </v-container>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'UserForm2fa',
    props: {
        id: { type: Number, required: true }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            tfaEnabled: false,
            google2fa: {
                token: '',
            },
            rules: {
                    required: val => !!val || 'Dit veld mag niet leeg zijn',
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeStatus() {
            this.$emit( 'change', this.tfaEnabled );
        },
        submit() {
            this.$emit('submit', this.token)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

My controller function:

```
public function update2faStatus( Update2faStatus $request ) {

    $user = User::findOrFail( $request->id );

    $tfaEnabled = $request->input('tfaEnabled', false);
    $user->tfaEnabled = $tfaEnabled;

    $user->save();
}
```

and my Method for this:

```
 toggle2fa( status ) {
            this.$store.dispatch( 'update2faStatus' )
            .then( () => this.$store.dispatch('addMessage', { success: true, content: ['2 Factor authenticatie is ingeschakeld.'] } ) )
            .catch( error =>  this.$store.dispatch( 'addMessage', { success: false, content: error.response.data} ))
        },
```

Comment: is there any error you are getting? or whats the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: I have on error on de @click="change" Property or method "change" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: You don't have a method called `change` on the vue component. Taking a quick glance at your code it should be `changeStatus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have not defined any method with name `change()`. `@change` event expects a method named `change()` in your code. But I guess you are trying to execute `changeStatus()` method when toggle button is changed. Changing your code to `@change="changeStatus()"` should fix the problem.